# create a list of an objectA inside the objectA

Tags: python, class, object, attributes

When I'm trying to `append()` the object itself into a list inside the object, it doesn't work, I don't understand why.

```
class PLayer:

    CLASS_NAME = "player"
    TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER = 0
    TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST = []
    PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT = 0

    def __init__(self, name,
                 first_name,
                 birthday,
                 note,
                 player_id=None,
                 total_score=None,
                 tournament_score=None):

        self.PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT += 1
        self.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER += 1
        self.name = name
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.player_id = self.PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT
        self.total_score = 0
        self.tournament_score = 0
        self.note = note
        self.TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST.append(self.Player)
```

So the class Player have a list `TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST = []`, then inside the `__init__` I want to add the player that have been freshly created to the list with the last line `self.TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST.append(self.Player)` but I get this error

```
line 25, in __init__
    self.TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST.append(self.Player)
AttributeError: 'PLayer' object has no attribute 'Player'
```

I don't understand why. I've tried to put and remove `self.`, the parenthesis also () for Player() .

Comment: Player.TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST.append(self)

Comment: Well, the class `PLayer` indeed does not have any attribute called player...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Remove the `.Player` attribute

If you do this, it works fine. Your class doesn't have any `Player` attribute. The player you want to add is referenced in the `self` variable, the instance.

```py
        self.TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST.append(self)
```

Let's see a simpler example with debug:

```py
class Player:
    TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER = 0
    TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST = []
    PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT += 1
        self.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER += 1
        self.name = name
        self.player_id = self.PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT
        self.TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}:<{self.player_id}>"

print(Player("Doe"))  # Doe:<1>
print(Player.TOTAL_PLAYER_LIST)  # [Doe:<1>]
```

## Other critical issue with your code

1. Name your class `Player`, not `PLayer`
2. Class attribute vs Instance attribute

```py
        self.PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT += 1
```

This won't change the class attribute `PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT`, just create an instance attribute of `1`:

```py
doe = Player("Doe")
joe = Player("joe")
print(Player.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER)  # 0
print(doe.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER)  # 1
print(joe.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER)  # 1
```

Fix this with:

```py
    def __init__(self, name):
        Player.PLAYER_ID_INCREMENT += 1
        Player.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER += 1
        ...

doe = Player("Doe")
joe = Player("joe")
print(Player.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER)  # 2
print(doe.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER)  # 2
print(joe.TOTAL_PLAYER_NUMBER)  # 2
```

This happens because integers are immutable and += will "rebind" the incremented value to a new reference located... in `self`, the instance namespace, not the class namespace.

A more pythonic way to do that is with metaclasses:

```py
import typing


class CountInstances(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        super().__init__(name, bases, dict_)
        cls.count = 0

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.count += 1
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class Player(metaclass=CountInstances):
    total_player_list: typing.Final = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.player_id = self.count
        self.total_player_list.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}:<{self.player_id}>"


doe = Player("Doe")
joe = Player("Joe")
print(Player.count)  # 2
print(doe.count)  # 2
print(joe.count)  # 2
print(Player.total_player_list)  # [Doe:<1>, Joe:<2>]
```

More information about metaclasses: [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/6251742)